# The datalist doesn't display all in window phone?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

I'm using data list control in Window Phone to display all 50 records from the XML file.

However, only few of them display on the page and I don't see the rest...

How can see all records in the same page?  I don't see any vertical bar or roll down on the Emulator?

Thanks

Comment: can you post your xaml with the list?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ScrollViewer so you can scroll up and down :)

Answer (score 0):

I just happened to put the mouse cursor in the middle of the page and move up and down and was able see all the records.

Btw, I did tested out by adding the ScrollViewer but it didn't work for me.